# Grey turns into pink in Adobe programs?

Tags: colors, color-profiles

I recently installed the Adobe Creative Suite 4 on my Windows machine. However, I'm getting this strange problem: certain shades of grey turn into pink. This happens in all the programs, and everywhere from the actual documents to even the interface. It looks like this:

[image]

Notice how some parts of the interface are normal, but others have a pink tint to them. It does the same thing in the actual document, like this:

[image]

The above image is supposed to be a gradient from black to white, but notice how the center appears more pink than grey. I've never had this problem with CS3 (at least not that I can recall).

I've checked the color profile settings and they seem to be the same as my monitor, so I'm not sure what could be causing this. Any ideas? I can provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance.

---

### My color management settings

#### Working Spaces:

RGB: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
CYMK: U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2

#### Color Management Policies:

RGB: Off
CYMK: Off

I have an Acer X221W monitor if that matters.

Comment: What are your color management settings set at? Edit -> Color Settings

Comment: Well, that's a good one. Not sure what to say at that point other than do a hardware calibration if you can get access to such a device, but I imagine if you had one you'd have already tried it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it. Apparently, in my Display Settings under Advanced, I had a different color profile set up, and so the one set in the Adobe programs and the one set on my monitor were clashing. When I set them to the same thing, everything worked.

Comment: This happened to me as well with my Samsung monitors.  The default color profiles that are downloaded by Microsoft Update for that monitor gave my adobe programs a orange/beige tint, made everything look like photos from the 70's.   I just removed the color profiles.

Comment: @Roy: Ah, that may be what it is! Before I upgraded to CS4, I reformatted my hard drive, and I probably just had all the default settings.

Comment: Happened to me after a re-install of XP. Apparently, years ago, I had corrected the problem, and it took me days to find out that it wasn't the Adobe color settings, but my monitor/driver color spaces causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough I came across the same problem - got new LCD monitor (DELL 2209WA) and after doing some graphics editing I noticed some gray shades were showing as pink.

I have a Radeon graphics card so I checked Catalyst settings and noticed in Digital panel -> Avivo Color settings -> Color temperature control that I had "Use Extended Display Identification Data" unchecked. After enabling it colors returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a graphics card, I suggest you make sure that the settings for the card is set so that the card doesn't control the color of your display.

In my nVidia control panel I have a setting where I can choose whether color is set by the card or by each individual application.